# e.which is not getting any value. If i put a watch on e.which its showing nothing even after keypress

Tags: jquery

Following is my Code. i am getting nothing for e.which even after key press.

```
$(function () {
        $(".NumAthlete").on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var Total = 0;
                $(".NumAthlete").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    }
                    else {
                        Total += parseInt($(this).val());
                    }
                });
                $(".TotalNumAthlete").val(parseInt(Total));
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you get for console.log(e.which);

Comment: console.log shows "nothing".

Comment: please post you HTML you are using for input

Comment: I tried this and it has worked for me , may be you have other errors in your page , please update the question with your full code, check this http://jsfiddle.net/9aco8gqj/

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya I think he want to prevent typing non numerals too

Comment: You're handling `input propertychange paste`; none of these are keyboard events -- thus no `event.which`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use keydown

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alenjoy333/6jzrerw5/)

```
    $(function () {
                $(".NumAthlete").on('keydown', function (e) {
 if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46)
                        return false;
                }
                    else {
                        var Total = 0;
                        $(".NumAthlete").each(function () {
                            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                            }
                            else {
                                Total += parseInt($(this).val());
                            }
                        });
                        $(".TotalNumAthlete").val(parseInt(Total));
                    };
                });
            });
```

Comment: this doesnt work with the numeric buttons on right side of keyboard ... also  last digit entered is skipped while calculating the total..

Comment: find the key codes for numeric keypads and include that keys in your if condition

Comment: what about the other part of problem

Comment: see the updated code... and for the second part find that by yourself